# Linking to a specific id from a clickable picture asp.net

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Products", "Home", new {id = "#Specialty"})">
   <img class="img-responsive img-thumbnails" 
                src="@Url.Content("~/images/ChopSaw.jpg")"/>
</a>
```

The code I have provided takes me to - `website.com/Home/Products/#Specialty`.

If I would like to navigate to - `website.com/Home/Products#Specialty.`

`(removed "/" between products & #Specialty)`

How would I do that? I will have to maintain the integrity and styling of the `img/link`. I have spent more time on this trying to get it to work than I would like to admit. Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one

```
 <a href='@Url.Action("Products", "Home")#Specialty'>
```

Comment: That did not work.. However, that idea spurred me to try this --                
  <a href='@Url.Action("Products", "Home")#Specialty'> and that DID work. I did not realize that it took all text after the controller and view as a literal. THANK you. I am upvoting this as an answer.

Comment: @ReRoute Yes. Thats true. Updated my answer